# How to show/hide Popup when I have a Tab Layout with multiple fragments being displayed in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-popupwindow

I have Tab Layout with multiple fragments and I would like to display a Popup only when a specific screen is being displayed. I am using the [Jetpack Compose Popup component](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary?authuser=1#popup).
I followed the docs and currently the popup is always being displayed regardless the fragment is being displayed, but I want to show the Popup only when a specific screen is being displayed.

Popup code:

```
Box {
val popupWidth = 200.dp
val popupHeight = 50.dp
val cornerSize = 16.dp

Popup(alignment = Alignment.Center) {
    // Draw a rectangle shape with rounded corners inside the popup
    Box(
        Modifier
            .size(popupWidth, popupHeight)
            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(cornerSize))
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive an old thread but for completeness sake, try using a boolean and an if statement that is true when you want the popup to be shown.

```kotlin
var showPopup by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val popupWidth = 200.dp
val popupHeight = 50.dp
val cornerSize = 16.dp

if (showPopup) {
    Popup(alignment = Alignment.Center, onDismissRequest = { showPopup = false }) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(popupWidth, popupHeight).background(Color.white, RoundedCornerShape(cornerSize)) {
            // content
        }
    }
}
```